# Confusion on definition of convergence / limit

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition:** For all natural numbers $n$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $|x-x_k| < 1/n$ $\forall k \geq m$

So we just pick a number $x$ in the interval of length $1/n$ to be the number the sequence converges to? Doesn’t that mean the number a sequence converges to is not unique because we can just pick any number? It’s confusing because in the limit, the interval shrinks dramatically but it will always still nonetheless be an interval and hence has more than 1 point, right? Another way of rephrasing is: the greater $n$ becomes, the smaller the interval $1/n$ is; we therefore have these "nested" intervals and $x$ must be in all these intervals. Isn't there more than one $x$ since an interval is not a single point?

Edit: After thought, my understanding is as follows: A sequence converges to only a single number because even if we have two points in an interval A, one of those points will no longer be in an interval B since B shrinks. And this continues for infinity (infinitesimally small). In other words, give me a tiny interval. Yes, that has multiple points. But then I'll give you an even tinier interval. And yes, that has multiple points. But then I'll give you a tinier version of that tinier interval. And this continues on and on. The number that persists in all those tiny intervals is the the number that's being converged to.

*Is this correct?*

Answer (score 1):

It means that no matter how small you make $1/n$ (e.g. by picking a very large $n$) you can always find a term in your sequence after which all terms are within a radius of $1/n$ from the limit.

Comment: I understand that in the abstract but the part that's strange for me is no matter how small you make $1/n$, there will always more than a single point in the interval, right?

Comment: It means that you choose an natural number $N$, then we find some term in our sequence which is sufficiently close to $x$. We call this $x_m$. So $\vert x - x_m \vert < 1/N$ Then every term after $m$, so $x_{m+1}, x_{m+2} \dots$ forever, will be within that same radius from $x$. 

The catch is then this applies for any choice of $N$, so I can make $N$ very very large, and have the $x_m$, that is guaranteed to exist, be extremely close to $x$

Comment: I see. So a sequence converges to only a single number because even if we have two points in an interval A, one of those points will no longer be in an interval B since B shrinks. And this continues for infinity (infinitesimally small).

Comment: In other words, give me a tiny interval. Yes, that has multiple points. But then I'll give you an even tinier interval. And yes, that has multiple points. But then I'll give you a tinier version of that tinier interval. And this continues on and on. The number that persists in all those tiny intervals is the the number that's being converged to.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $x$ and $y$ with the property which you mentioned
then for any $n$ you can choose a  $m$ such that $\mid x_k -x\mid < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\mid x_k -y\mid < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $k \ge m$

Then for all $n$, and for $k \ge m$ $$ \mid x -y \mid \le \mid x-x_k \mid + \mid x_k -y\mid < \frac{2}{n} $$ by the triangle inequality.

So for all $n$, $\mid x-y\mid < \frac2n$.

Since the RHS can be made arbitrarily smaller we have $x=y$ which means given a sequence converges, it always converges to a unique point.